# How to generate a proper AES key in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I'm new to working with encryption, and I understand that the Key needs to be 128, 192, or 256 bits. Is there a proper way to generate a key? Currently in my project, I have multiple users, and if needed, I can grab the password of someone who logs in and hash it with sha256, but can I just use that as the key somehow? Or is there a better way to generate these keys? I'm using the encrypt package and AES is CBC mode, so with that, I dont know how to generate a proper key for each user, and I would rather not hardcode a key that everyone uses if possible. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Look into "password based key derivation functions" e.g. scrypt

Comment: You can have a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/aes_ecb_pkcs5_flutter